# Mongodb driver - check if GuidSerializer is already registered

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm calling

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.CSharpLegacy));
```

to register GuidSerializer as CSharpLegacy in global scope.
If called more than once, this calls throws exception with the following message

```
  Message=There is already a serializer registered for type Guid.
```

Is there a way to check whether GuidSerializer is already registered?
Would it make sense to unregister and re-register it again?

I know this error is expected, of course. I'm curious about confident (verified) approach to check if GuidSerializer is already registered before making such attempt.

The mongodb drvier version for C# is 2.11.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you call `GetSerializer`, then a serializer is created and cached, unles one is already cached.

I think the only way to properly handle this, is to register a `SerializationProvider` instead of a serializer.

When the "serializer registry" creates a serializer for a type, it asks all the providers in turn if they support the type, and use the first one. So it doesn't really matter if you add the same provider 3 or 4 times.

```
class CsharpLegacyGuidSerializationProvider : IBsonSerializationProvider
{
    public IBsonSerializer GetSerializer(Type type)
    {
        if(type == typeof(Guid))
            return new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.CSharpLegacy); 
            
        return null;
    }
}

// Register provider three times - no point, but proves it works and does not throw.
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializationProvider(new CsharpLegacyGuidSerializationProvider());
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializationProvider(new CsharpLegacyGuidSerializationProvider());
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializationProvider(new CsharpLegacyGuidSerializationProvider());
    
var currentRepresentation = (BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer(typeof(Guid)) as GuidSerializer).GuidRepresentation;
Debug.Assert(currentRepresentation == GuidRepresentation.CSharpLegacy);
```

Now, if you serialize anything containing a Guid *before* you register this provider, it won't help, since the 'wrong' serializer will be cached in the registry.

Comment: Awesome. Very well explained. I like it.
Thanks for the note about serialization before registering provider. 
It really happens in static constructor, so before anything else is done. The problem I had is that the static constructor was called multiple times, since the class was generic.